# More than one node on the same host?

Tags: rabbitmq

I've been following the RabbitMQ guide on [clustering](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html), I'm using RabbitMQ version 2.8.7 and I'm attempting to launch 2 nodes on the same host. I'm launching both nodes the same way, using the following commands...

```
RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5674 RABBITMQ_PID_FILE='/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit-disc' RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit-disc rabbitmq-server -detached

RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673 RABBITMQ_PID_FILE='/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit-ram' RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit-ram rabbitmq-server -detached
```

I then attempt to add the second node to a cluster with the first one by stopping it, using the following command...

```
sudo rabbitmqctl -n rabbit-ram stop_app
```

However, rather than stopping it simply hangs on...

```
Stopping node 'rabbit-ram@test-01' ...
```

It never completes stopping the node. I've looked at both the log files and pid output itself and neither throw any error or offer any hints as to why the process is locking when I try and stop or issue it any command for that matter.

I've also tried providing completely different values for other arguments in the start commands including `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE` thinking there may be some locking issue but that doesn't solve anything.

I've got the following plugins installed:

```
 [e] amqp_client                       2.8.7
 [e] erlando                           2.8.7
 [e] mochiweb                          2.3.1-rmq2.8.7-gitd541e9a
 [E] rabbitmq_management               2.8.7
 [e] rabbitmq_management_agent         2.8.7
 [e] rabbitmq_mochiweb                 2.8.7
 [E] rabbitmq_shovel                   2.8.7
 [E] rabbitmq_shovel_management        2.8.7
 [e] webmachine                        1.9.1-rmq2.8.7-git52e62bc
```

Any help on figuring out why the locking is occurring and how to overcome it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears running the `rabbitmq_management` plugin and its dependencies causes the issue. Running multiple nodes with it disabled isn't a problem, however when I enable it on its own it enables all of the following too...

```
* mochiweb-2.3.1-rmq2.8.7-gitd541e9a
* rabbitmq_management_agent-2.8.7
* rabbitmq_mochiweb-2.8.7
* webmachine-1.9.1-rmq2.8.7-git52e62bc
```

These appear to be causing a clash. I'd assume because they web view is trying to launch on every node when it's already taken up on the original node. I could dig around the configs to have multiple webviews but it's not needed. Disabling these plugins after my first node launches is a sufficient fix for me.